# Slowdown in Game of Life with Objects - Why?

Tags: javascript, object, p5.js, conways-game-of-life

I am working on recreating Game of Life in different ways, taking Coding Train’s video as the starting point. What I am trying to add is ‘color inheritance’: A newborn cell ‘inheriting’ the color from the average of the neighbouring cells’ colours.

I have made two versions: The first one has a 2D grid array for cells, and each cell is an array with RGB values.

```
grid[i][j] = [255,0,100]
```

A for loop iterates through the grid array and draws boxes of the right colour on the right position on the canvas. It then checks if the cell should be alive or dead next generation. **This works fine without any slowdown, no matter the size of the grid.**

https://editor.p5js.org/umutreldem/sketches/1qCmEzHlY

The second version fills each element of the grid array with Cell objects. This object receives its coordinates on the grid and its size. The color is given relative to its position on the grid.

```
function Cell(x, y, size) {
this.x = x * size;
this.y = y * size;
this.size = size;

//...

this.r = x * 10;
this.g = y * 10;
this.b = x+y;
```

The Cell object has functions for determining how many alive neighbours it has, inheriting colour from neighbours, etc. It is the same process as the first version. Then in draw() the grid is looped twice: once for determining the next status of each cell, and once for changing the cells to their new state.

**This version experiences massive slowdown, especially at higher resolutions.**
https://editor.p5js.org/umutreldem/sketches/2skO6-2Cm

I would like to add more features to this, such as keeping count of the age of each cell (for how long it is alive,) and using making an object for each cell makes more sense to me.

With my limited experience with p5.js / JavaScript in general, I cannot understand why this is the case. The function of both versions is the same (apart from one extra loop in the second version), so why does the second version tax the computer this much?

Comment: Remember that upping the size is a _quadratic_ increase. Going from 400x400 to 800x800 is a four-fold increase of the original workload. Going to 1600x1600 (say, because of high-dpi screens) is now eight times as slow as the original 400x400. So the question is _what kind_ of slowdown are you seeing? The expected quadratic slowdown, or something that is outside of the expected?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am wondering why exactly the second version experiences the massive slowdown, whereas the first does not. The links in the OP lead to the p5.js editor with the code, you can see how the first one is very smooth while the second one is not, even though they are the same resolution. If it were quadratic slowdown I imagine both versions would experience similar levels.

Comment: Links to code are fine, but [only in addition to putting it in your post](/help/how-to-ask), too. External links expire, which would make this question basically meaningless in the future, which would be a shame. Also a few observations: why are you declaring functions inside functions inside functions? It looks very much like that `function cell` really should be a `class Cell { constructor() { ... } .. }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example (using objects) you draw a every square, even if it is "empty". 
In your first example, you only draw a square when the cell is active, and thus save computation by not drawing black squares on a black background :)

You can simply comment out the `else` statement in the "object version" to get the same computational savings.

```
this.show = function() {

    if (this.status == 1) {
      fill(color(this.r, this.g, this.b));
      stroke(0);
      square(this.x, this.y, this.size);
    }
    // else {
    //       fill(20);
    //       stroke(0);
    //       square(this.x, this.y, this.size);
    //   }
  }
```

[Here](https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/zNfiqr-kq) is a modified version, which seems to work reasonably fast.

Comment: I also saw that you looped twice through all the neighbors of a cell, when the color of that cell got updated (once to count the number of neighbors, once to get their colors). I combined both into one loop. This seems to make it faster at the beginning of the game when there are many colors to be determined. It makes less of a difference when there are many stable states and thus not many colors have to be updated.

Comment: Yup- that seems to be it. Thank you for the post and the fixes!

Comment: If this answer answers your question, maybe consider clicking the tick mark left of the answer.